# Why is this question off topic

Tags: discussion

Why is this question off topic on an expat site : [Does Australian Medicare cover me internationally?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/116/does-australian-medicare-cover-me-internationally) ?

Answer (score 3):

It's about your 'trips abroad' - it'd be a great travel question.  If it was 'does it cover me while LIVING abroad', that'd be different.

That's my view, at least.  In these early days of beta, we need to be strict and precise.

Comment: +1 Question clearly belongs on Travel.SE.

Comment: Anybody with enough knowledge of Australian Medicare to answer authoritatively would have to know both, I don't see much value in the distinction. The best is to (re)formulate the question more broadly and to describe under what conditions you might be covered or not.